# I want to pass the json data to the backend using square bracket instead if curly bracket in grails

Tags: json, grails

this is the backend of grails to retrieve data

```
def addMessageA() {

    JSONObject requestJson= request.JSON;
    Message message = new Message();
    message.message = requestJson.message;
    message.category = Category.get(requestJson.cId);
    message.heading = requestJson.heading;
    message.date= new Date();
    message.electionArea = ElectionArea.get(requestJson.eId)
    message.palika = Palika.get(requestJson.pId)
    message.ward = Ward.get(requestJson.wId)
    message.member = requestJson.name;
    def fbId = requestJson.memberFbId
    message.memberFbId = fbId;
    message.phone = requestJson.phone;

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    if (message.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)) {
        object.put("save", "success")
    } else {
        object.put("save", "fail")
    }
    render object;
}
```

and this is the format where its working but i want to use square bracket instead of curly bracket.And i am using post method.

this is url of the backend

http://localhost:8080/back/message/addMessageA

and this is the format of sending data to backend json format where i want to use square bracket instead of curly bracket.

{
    message : "कुल गार्हस्थ उत्पादन वृद्धिदर ६.९४ प्रतिशत पुग्ने",
    cId : "3",
    heading : "कुल ",
    eId : "70",
    pId : "740",
    wId : "5555",
    name : "सुमन sir",
    memberFbId : "012306547891234",
    phone : "986032764"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is a specific syntax and format (see http://www.json.org/). It is designed to be minimal, but this minimal syntax is designed to represent data elements very concretely. In short,

- Braces (**{** … **}**) define objects and
- Brackets (**[** … **]**) define arrays
- Object elements are each labeled
- Array elements are not labeled

Literally replacing the braces with brackets would no longer be consistent with JSON syntax.

```
[ message : " … ", cId : "3", heading : " … ", eId : "70", pId : "740", wId : "5555", name : " … ", memberFbId : "012306547891234", phone : "986032764" 
]
```

Why must the content be wrapped in brackets? Depending on your answer, one option could be to wrap the existing object in brackets, creating an array of 1 element.

```
[ { message : " … ",cId : "3", heading : " … ", eId : "70", pId : "740", wId : "5555", name : " … ", memberFbId : "012306547891234", phone : "986032764" 
  } 
]
```

This is legal JSON. I am not sure whether `request.JSON`'s JSONObject will interpret this properly (there used to be problems with that). You can, instead pull the body content via its getInputStream() and use a JSON parser to interpret the text as a JSON array. Then the first element of the array is the same as the object used in the current implementation.

Alternatively, you could read the content text, covert the opening and closing brackets with braces to convert the non-JSON to valid JSON, convert it to a JSONObject, and continue from there.

Comment: thank you wrlee but can you explain me with some sample code if you don not mind

Comment: Be aware that if your JSON's outer wrapper is brackets '[]' and not braces '{}', you are in fact sending an array of JSON object, not a single JSON object, which is a big semantic difference. If the API expects or requires an array, then that is fine. Otherwise, not so good.

Comment: @LaxmanMagar never indicated why he "didn't like" the default JSON structure whether the semantic change is relevant to him. It also might affect how an would be implemented.

Comment: Thanks You for your suggestions guys.